# Combining form post with multiple drop down JS reload

Tags: php, javascript, post, drop-down-menu

So basically I have a form that submits a new article to the database.

When submitted, the page validates the entries and displays errors and uses `$_POST` to repopulate the fields to allow the user to fix the errors. This works fine. Here is the code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="newArticle.php?action=add">
    <p>&nbsp;Title:<br />
        <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="30" 
                value="<?=$HTTP_POST_VARS['title']?>">
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;Tagline:<br />
        <input name="tagline" type="text" id="tagline" size="30" 
                value="<?=$HTTP_POST_VARS['tagline']?>">
    </p>
```

I have now added 3 drop down menus to select the section, each populated from the db by a JS reload after making a selection from the previous list. These also work fine.
Like this:

```
<? //////////        Starting of first drop downlist /////////
echo "<select name='country' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
    if($noticia2['id']==@$country){
        echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[id]'>$noticia2[name]</option>"."<BR>";}
    else{
        echo  "<option value='$noticia2[id]'>$noticia2[name]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";
//////////////////  This will end the first drop down list ///////////

//////////        Starting of second drop downlist /////////
echo "<select name='region' onchange=\"reload3(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) { 
    if($noticia['id']==@$region){
        echo "<option selected value='$noticia[id]'>$noticia[name]</option>"."<BR>";}
    else{
        echo  "<option value='$noticia[id]'>$noticia[name]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";
//////////////////  This will end the second drop down list ///////////


//////////        Starting of third drop downlist /////////
echo "<select name='resort' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer3)) { 
    echo  "<option value='$noticia[id]'>$noticia[name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
//////////////////  This will end the third drop down list ///////////?>
```

The JavaScript is:

```
<script language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form)
    {
        var val=form.country.options[form.country.options.selectedIndex].value; 
        self.location='newArticle.php?country=' + val ;
    }
    function reload3(form)
    {
        var val=form.country.options[form.country.options.selectedIndex].value; 
        var val2=form.region.options[form.region.options.selectedIndex].value; 

        self.location='newArticle.php?country=' + val + '&region=' + val2 ;
    }
</script>
```

My problem is that the form fields are empty after a reload from using the dropdowns, essentially meaning the user must start again.

Is there a sensible way to make this work, or an alternate way to populate the fields on post/reload? It seems a complicated way of doing things.

I would much prefer to use PHP to update the dropdowns using post but I ran into problems when changing the fist dropdown after the others had been selected.

Comment: you're changing self.location, which reloads the entire page. instead, how about using ajax and more intelligent processing that just loads in the values for the latter dropdowns when something is selected in a previous one?

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the comments, when you change the location of the page using `self.location =`, you lose all data in the form.

Instead of `self.location='newArticle.php?country=' + val + '&region=' + val2 ;` why not just post the form using `form.submit()`?